# Get parent name from the children id with level in Oracle

Tags: oracle, hierarchical

I would like to retrieve the Name of the Parent from the Cildren Id in a query thanks to the ORACLE feature "CONNECT BY"

```
SELECT contact_id, contact_name,parent_id, LEVEL
   FROM contacts
   CONNECT BY PRIOR contact_id = parent_id;
```

But I would like also retrieve the name of the parent, and I try many times, but I cannot obtain that I want. Could you please help me with that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PRIOR with name column as well.

```
SELECT  contact_id, contact_name,parent_id, LEVEL, prior contact_name
  FROM  contacts
CONNECT BY PRIOR contact_id = parent_id;
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working. Do you know how to retrieve the grandparent ? is it the same way ?

Comment: You should search for CONNECT_BY_ROOT.